# Binding to nested Items

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}">
    ....
    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Class1}">
        ...
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Class_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

The problem is that I am getting the binding of Classes and not of Class1. I want the Class1 binding in Tapped CommandParameter. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: without knowing anything about the types of `Classes` or `Class1` it's difficult to say

Comment: Have you tried using a [RelativeSource binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor) to specify the ancestor binding context type?

Comment: Thanks. @Jason, it is just an object I want to reference.

Comment: @AndrewH, is that not for referencing the parent? I want to reference the child.

Comment: According to your XAML hierarchy the TapGestureRecognizer is attached to the StackLayout bound to `Class1`. Unless your XAML snippet is incorrect, the BindingContext of the TapGestureRecognizer should already be `Class1`. I'm not sure what you mean by referencing the child. You can't bind to a child's BindingContext.

Comment: You are right. By mistake I put it outside the datatemplate. Now it works! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `inner StackLayout` into the `DataTemplate` of the `outer StackLayout` , the BindingContext of the `TapGestureRecognizer`  must be `Class1` .

```
   <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Class1}">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Class_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: You are right. By mistake I put it outside the datatemplate which is obviously wrong. Thank you!